# SWF object not work in HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, object, embed, flash, swfobject

I have problem with my .SWF banner, when I open direct object http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf, everything works good, but when I placed this object into html website, there is a problem with opening articles after onclick on articles image/title. Where could be a problem?

**EMBEDING CODE**

```
<object width="160" height="600">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf">
<embed src="http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf" width="160" height="600">
</embed>
</object>
```

**BANNER CODE ACTIONSCRIPT 3**

```
ar xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/banner.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
   xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

t1.htmlText= "<a href='" + xmlData.clanok[0].link + "'>" + xmlData.clanok[0].title + "</a>";
t2.htmlText= "<a href='" + xmlData.clanok[1].link + "'>" + xmlData.clanok[1].title + "</a>";
t3.htmlText= "<a href='" + xmlData.clanok[2].link + "'>" + xmlData.clanok[2].title + "</a>";


import flash.net.URLRequest;

var imageLoader:Loader;
var imageRequest:URLRequest;

imageLoader = new Loader();
imageRequest = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[0].foto);
imageLoader.load(imageRequest);

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showPic);


var imageLoader2:Loader;
var imageRequest2:URLRequest;

imageLoader2 = new Loader();
imageRequest2 = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[1].foto);
imageLoader2.load(imageRequest2);

imageLoader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showPic);



var imageLoader3:Loader;
var imageRequest3:URLRequest;

imageLoader3 = new Loader();
imageRequest3 = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[2].foto);
imageLoader3.load(imageRequest3);

imageLoader3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showPic);


function showPic(e:Event):void
{

    var imageHolder: Sprite = new Sprite();
    imageHolder.addChild(imageLoader.content);

    imageHolder.buttonMode = true;
    imageHolder.width = 140;
    imageHolder.height = 87;
    imageHolder.x = 10;
    imageHolder.y = 65;

    imageHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked1);

    addChild(imageHolder);



    var imageHolder2: Sprite = new Sprite();
    imageHolder2.addChild(imageLoader2.content);

    imageHolder2.buttonMode = true;
    imageHolder2.width = 140;
    imageHolder2.height = 87;
    imageHolder2.x = 10;
    imageHolder2.y = 245;

    imageHolder2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked2);

    addChild(imageHolder2); 



    var imageHolder3: Sprite = new Sprite();
    imageHolder3.addChild(imageLoader3.content);

    imageHolder3.buttonMode = true;
    imageHolder3.width = 140;
    imageHolder3.height = 87;
    imageHolder3.x = 10;
    imageHolder3.y = 425;

    imageHolder3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked3);

    addChild(imageHolder3); 

}       

function buttonClicked1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var buttonClicked1: URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[0].link);
    navigateToURL(buttonClicked1, "_self");
}

function buttonClicked2(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var buttonClicked2: URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[1].link);
    navigateToURL(buttonClicked2, "_self");
}

function buttonClicked3(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var buttonClicked3: URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[2].link);
    navigateToURL(buttonClicked3, "_self");
}

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a security problem, you should allow your swf to open links in the same window ( the `_self` target) that's why you should add `allowScriptAccess` with `value="always"` :

```
<object width="160" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf" width="160" height="600" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
</object>
```